# how to get IIS to work with dbf files?

Tags: asp.net, iis, foxpro, dbf

problem is the following:
raised the IIS server on Windows XP, but when accessing the dbf files crashes exception.
driver to work with files vfpoledb set. out of the visual studio everything works fine.

could something else be done?

Comment: The 'vfpoledb.1' provider is not registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its case sensitive or not, but the connection string should be something like

String connString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source= C:\Your\Path\OnIISMachine\YourDatabase.dbc;"

If that's ok, then do you have the proper OleDB driver from [Microsoft Link for OleDB Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1A87D8F-2D58-491F-A0FA-95A3289C5FD4&displaylang=en)

-- REVISION FROM COMMENT

Does the SERVER have the OleDb Provider installed... it is required on any machine that will be running the code.  So, testing on your machine (XP) running IIS works fine because you have the OleDB provider on your machine.  Then, you deploy the app to the server and it doesn't, it can't connect.  Is THAT what is happening?

Comment: Yes, the connection string is spelled correctly. checked in the debugger ... out of the studio is working correctly.
but out of the server - exception

Comment: already done. The reason is simple: the folder with the files needed to set permissions separately, despite the fact that it lies at the root of the Web site.
I thank all